# React Native touchable opacity margin expands the clickable area

Tags: react-native, margin, touchableopacity

So I have this code below, but when I add margins to my buttons in their styling like marginTop and marginLeft  (shomeButton, mhomeButtom, and abthomeButton specifically), the clickable area for said button is expanded to whatever margins I have added. I tried using absolute positioning instead but that made it so it required many clicks for the buttons to work. Is there any fix? Thanks!

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Image, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';
 
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <LinearGradient colors={['#1155CC', 'transparent']} style={styles.background}/>
        <Text style={styles.titleText}>GEO</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Single')}>
          <LinearGradient colors={['#00FFFE', '#31f48e']} style={styles.singleButton}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>  Single Player  </Text>
          </LinearGradient>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Multi')}>
          <LinearGradient colors={['#00FFFE', '#31f48e']} style={styles.multiButton}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>  Multi-Player  </Text>
          </LinearGradient>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('About')}>
          <LinearGradient colors={['#00FFFE', '#31f48e']} style={styles.creditButton}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>  About  </Text>
          </LinearGradient>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Image style={styles.tinyLogo} resizeMode="cover" source={require('./assets/earth-icon.png')}/>
    </View>
 
  );
}
 
function SingleScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <LinearGradient colors={['#1155CC', 'transparent']} style={styles.background}/>
      <Text style={styles.titleText}>GEO</Text>
      <Text style={styles.underText}>Single</Text>
      <Text style={styles.normText}>Last Answer:</Text>
      <Text style={styles.normundText}>Arizona</Text>
      <Text style={styles.normunaText}>Word: </Text>
      <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Your Answer" />
      <Text style={styles.normunsText}>Incorrect/ Correct</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}>
        <LinearGradient colors={['#00FFFE', '#31f48e']} style={styles.shomeButton}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>  Home  </Text>
        </LinearGradient>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
 
function MultiScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <LinearGradient colors={['#1155CC', 'transparent']} style={styles.background}/>
      <Text style={styles.titleText}>GEO</Text>
      <Text style={styles.underText}>Multi</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}>
        <LinearGradient colors={['#00FFFE', '#31f48e']} style={styles.mhomeButton}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>  Home  </Text>
        </LinearGradient>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

function AboutScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <LinearGradient colors={['#1155CC', 'transparent']} style={styles.background}/>
      <Text style={styles.titleText}>GEO</Text>
      <Text style={styles.underText}>About</Text>
      <Text style={styles.creditText}>Creators: Anonymous</Text>
      <Text style={styles.credit2Text}>Version Number: 0.0.0</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}>
        <LinearGradient colors={['#00FFFE', '#31f48e']} style={styles.abthomeButton}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>  Home  </Text>
        </LinearGradient>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
 
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
 
function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Single" component={SingleScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Multi" component={MultiScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="About" component={AboutScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
 
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#4db4d7',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  titleText: {
    fontFamily: 'serif',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 100,
    color: '#31f48e',
  },
  underText: {
    fontFamily: 'serif',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 50,
    color: '#31f48e',
  },
  singleButton: {
    backgroundColor: '#31f48e',
    borderRadius: 20,
    elevation: 20,
    height: 50,
    marginTop: 40,
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontFamily: 'serif',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 30,
    color: '#ffffff',
  },
  multiButton: {
    backgroundColor: '#31f48e',
    borderRadius: 20,
    elevation: 20,
    height: 50,
    marginTop: 40,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  tinyLogo: {
    width: 380,
    height: 380,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  abthomeButton: {
    backgroundColor: '#31f48e',
    borderRadius: 20,
    elevation: 20,
    height: 50,
    marginTop: 210,
    marginLeft: 225,
  },
  background: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    height: 500,
  },
  creditButton: {
    backgroundColor: '#31f48e',
    borderRadius: 20,
    elevation: 20,
    height: 50,
    marginTop: 20,
    marginBottom: 35,
  },
  creditText: {
    fontFamily: 'serif',
    fontSize: 25,
    color: '#000000',
    marginTop: 150,
  },
  credit2Text: {
    fontFamily: 'serif',
    fontSize: 25,
    color: '#000000',
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  credit3Text: {
    fontFamily: 'serif',
    fontSize: 25,
    color: '#000000',
    marginTop: 5,
  },
   mhomeButton: {
    backgroundColor: '#31f48e',
    borderRadius: 20,
    elevation: 20,
    height: 50,
    marginTop: 550,
    marginLeft: 230,
  },
  shomeButton: {
    backgroundColor: '#31f48e',
    borderRadius: 20,
    elevation: 20,
    height: 50,
    marginTop: 220,
    marginLeft: 230,
  },
  normText: {
    fontFamily: 'serif',
    fontSize: 30,
    color: '#000000',
    marginTop: 50,
  },
  normundText: {
    fontFamily: 'serif',
    fontSize: 30,
    color: '#000000',
  },
  normunsText: {
    fontFamily: 'serif',
    fontSize: 30,
    color: '#000000',
    marginTop: 25
  },
  normunaText: {
    fontFamily: 'serif',
    fontSize: 25,
    color: '#000000',
    marginTop: 25
  },
  input: {
    height: 40,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 10,
    padding: 10,
    marginTop: 25,
  },
});
 
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding style with flex 1, it worked for me.